# References in Perl: Array of Hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, reference, perl-data-structures

I want to iterate through a reference to an array of hashes without having to make local copies, but I keep getting Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" errors. Why? How do I fix it?

```
sub hasGoodCar {
  my @garage = (
                { 
                 model => "BMW",
                 year  => 1999
                },

                { 
                 model  => "Mercedes",
                 year   => 2000
                },
               );

  run testDriveCars( \@garage );
}    

sub testDriveCars {
  my $garage = @_;

  foreach my $car ( @{$garage} ) { # <===========  Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" error
  return 1 if $car->{model} eq "BMW";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line

```
my $garage = @_;
```

assigns the length of `@_` to garage.  In the call to the `testDriveCars` method you pass a single arg, hence the length is one, hence your error message about `"1"`.

You could write

```
my ( $garage ) = @_;
```

or perhaps

```
my $garage = shift;
```

instead.

There's a missing semicolon in the posting too - after the assignment of `@garage`.

See [perldoc perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) for the details.

Comment: This common error comes from not understanding context.  Assignment to a scalar produces a scalar context, thus `@_` is evaluated as a scalar (which yields the length).